# Asp.net Mvc 4 Awesome PopupFormAction with only one button

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-awesome

How can I hide the Ok button in Awesome Popup Form Action

this my code:

```
@{
    var DetailFormat = string.Format("<button type='button' class='awe-btn' onclick=\"{0}\"><span class='ico-edit'></span></button>",
        Url.Awe().PopupFormAction().Title("Détail article").CancelText("Fermer").Height(500)
            .Url(Url.Action("Details", new { Id = ".Id" })));
}
```

I want to hide The Ok button it in the PopupForm having the Title "Détail"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in latest version (3.5) you can call

```
.ShowDefaultButtons(false)
```

this is used in the wizard demo http://demo.aspnetawesome.com/WizardDemo

and after call `.Button` to add any buttons you need

Answer (score 1):

With use of `.hide()`:

```
$('.awe-btn').hide();
```

The matter of fact is that `you have to mention your situation or scenario` where and how do you want to hide it.

### update:

```
$('.awe-btn[title="Détail"]').hide();
```

Comment: I want to hide The Ok button it in the PopupForm having the Title "Détail"